# How to digital sign jfrog artifacts?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jfrog-cli

I have a Jenkins job which uploads zip files to JFrog, I want to know is there any way I can digital sign jfrog artifacts i.e. zip file? Suggest anything that helps me on my query.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer to my self! Used gpg linux command for signing the artifact.

> Linux command to sign a zip artifact:

```
gpg --batch --passphrase ' K$7uK_wnwE' --sign abc.zip
```

> Linux command to verify the signed artifact:

```
gpg --verify abc.zip.gpg
```

> Linux command to remove the sign from artifact and get the original artifact:

```
gpg --decrypt -o cba.zip abc.zip.gpg
```

Answer (score 0):

For non-Docker artifacts, there isn't such a capability.

Generally, you are able to sign any artifact prior to uploading it to Artifactory, and instruct users how to verify it outside of Artifactory (post download).